# Start the TFS Web Test Runner From a URL

Tags: tfs

I'm writing a scenario-based manual test script and would like to reference my TFS test cases for detailed steps, so the script can just say "Add an item to the cart by running Test Case 1100" instead of including all the steps needed in the script.

Is there a way to directly start running a test case from a URL in TFS?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more description to your question, as I am not clear with your issue. Are you trying to execute a test case inside another test case?

Comment: I  don't think there is a way to execute a testcase from with-in a test case, other than shared steps, which I may end up doing. What I was hoping to do was write a Word document or HTML page that could actually launch a test case so I can order the cases in a way that makes sense as part of an extended scenario. test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly run tests in TFS with Typemock's [SmartRunner Task](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Frunningsmartrunnertask.htm), It integrates with TFS, TeamCity, and more build servers.
It is part of the Isolator bundle, I think it has a free version, you should check it.

Comment: Thanks, I've moved on to another project so I can't validate your answer, but I'll give the Accept anyway.